# Name of this graph partitioning problem? (related to coloring)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, graph-colouring, partition-problem

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k$, find a partition $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_k$ of $V$ into $k$ parts that minimize the total number of edges between two vertices in the same part, *i.e.* $\sum_i |(P_i\times P_i)\cap E|$.

May someone please provide the name of this problem and/or references?

If $k$ is larger than or equal to the chromatic number of $G$, then the number of edges under concern is $0$. But if $k$ is lower than the chromatic number, then it is strictly positive. Also, it is trivially bounded by $m=|E|$ (in the case $k=1$).

Comment: If you are not interested in approximations, then you can equally well look at the question of maximizing the number of edges between different parts, and this is usually known as *"maximum k-cut"* and also *"maximum k-colorable subgraph"*.

Comment: Thank you @JukkaSuomela, this seems like the answer I was looking for; please post it as an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Copied from a comment:)

If you are not interested in approximations, then you can equally well look at the question of maximizing the number of edges between different parts, and this is usually known as *"maximum k-cut"* and also *"maximum k-colorable subgraph"*.

Answer (score 1):

I think under typical terminology this would be called "Min k-Uncut" (note, Min Uncut asks for a partition into two that minimizes the number of edges not cut, and Max k-Uncut asks for a k partition maximizing the number of uncut edges). Googling seems to find some references.